# How to fill with a different color an area in seaborn.distplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Is it possible to fill with a color the area outside the two threshold lines (line1 and line2) and limited in Y-axis by the KDE curve drawn by distplot ?(that represents 3-sigmas for my application)

```
import pylab as pl
import seaborn as sns
#plotting the two lines
p1 = pl.axvline(x=line1,color='#EF9A9A')
p2 = pl.axvline(x=line2,color='#EF9A9A')
#plotting the PDF
sns.distplot(stat, hist=True,color='#388E3C')
```

[image: result figure]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use `fill_between` to fill the area underneath a curve. To get access to the KDE curve from the seaborn plot, you can draw that one first, such that `ax.lines` only has a single element, which is the curve of interest. Its data is obtained via `kde_x, kde_y = ax.lines[0].get_data()`.

Then using `ax.fill_between()` allows to fill the area under the curve. To restrict this to be outside some given data range, the `where` keyword argument may be used (and `interpolate=True` should be set to have the area go up to the points in question).

```
ax.fill_between(kde_x, kde_y, where=(kde_x<x0) | (kde_x>x1) , 
                interpolate=True, color='#EF9A9A')
```

Full example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

stat=np.random.randn(100)
x0 = -1
x1 = 1

#plotting the PDF (do this before plotting anything else)
ax = sns.distplot(stat, hist=True,color='#388E3C')
kde_x, kde_y = ax.lines[0].get_data()

#plotting the two lines
p1 = plt.axvline(x=x0,color='#EF9A9A')
p2 = plt.axvline(x=x1,color='#EF9A9A')


ax.fill_between(kde_x, kde_y, where=(kde_x<x0) | (kde_x>x1) , 
                interpolate=True, color='#EF9A9A')

plt.show()
```

[image: Image produced by the above code]

---

Old answer to initial question:

You may use an [`axvspan`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvspan.html), starting at the left x limit and going to the position of the first line and another one starting at the position of the second line and going to the right x limit.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

stat=np.random.randn(100)
x0 = -1
x1 = 1

#plotting the two lines
p1 = plt.axvline(x=x0,color='#EF9A9A')
p2 = plt.axvline(x=x1,color='#EF9A9A')

#plotting the PDF
ax = sns.distplot(stat, hist=True,color='#388E3C')

xlim = ax.get_xlim()
ax.axvspan(xlim[0], x0, color='#EF9A9A', alpha=0.5)
ax.axvspan(x1, xlim[1], color='#EF9A9A', alpha=0.5)
#reset xlim
ax.set_xlim(xlim)
plt.show()
```

[image: Image produced by the above code]

Here, we need to adjust the xlimits after setting spans; the reason is that with the spans in place the autoscaling would add another 5% padding to both ends of the axes, resulting in white space. Alternatively you could use zero margin for the xaxis, `ax.margins(x=0)`.

Comment: Why do you need to reset the x limits after doing this?

Comment: @DavidG I guess it would be more obvious if images where currently accessible, but I added an explanation in the answer.

Comment: Thank you @ImportanceOfBeingErnest.
But this solution fill color in all area less than x0 and greater to x1 !
There is a way to limit this area by the Gaussian curve drown by distplot (like the left side in this figure: https://imgur.com/WOSP4Mf )?

Comment: it didn't work for me. I got the initial figure (without coloring any area) !
is it normal when I do print 
print(kde_x)
print(kde_y)
I got:
[-0.016547415293142041, -0.016547415293142041]
[0, 1]

Comment: No, they both should have much more than 2 elements. What happens, if you replace `ax.lines[0]` by `ax.lines[-1]`? Which version of matplotlib are you using?

Comment: Thank you so much @ImportanceOfBeingErnest .. it works with ax.lines[-1]
I am using matplotlib 2.1.0

Comment: The code from the answer works fine with matplotlib 2.1. You probably ignored my comment about plotting the distplot before anything else. But if `ax.lines[-1]` works well for you, you can keep it like this.

Comment: Yes it works now with <code>ax.lines[0]</code> ... I start by distplot before anything. Sorry I didn't see your comment. Thank you so much @ImportanceOfBeingErnest