# How to fill another colour for range of distribution on a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a uniformly distributed histogram plot obtained using a) Seaborn and b) Matplotlib for which I want a particular region under the curve or on the histogram to be highlighted with a different colour.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

sns.set()

x = np.random.uniform(45,60, 1000)

#With Seaborn
sns.distplot(x)
plt.fill_between(50,55, color='g')

#With Matplotlib
plt.hist(x)
plt.fill_between(50,55)
```

However, I get an error saying I have too many indices for array.

How do I fill under the curve or the histogram for the given range with another colour on the same plot?

Comment: Did you look at how other people do this kind of partial filling?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest - Yes, I read the Matplotlib documentation and a few posts by other users, but, I only got errors/ did not understand the implementation/ got the incorrect display (Eg: Using axvspan)

Comment: For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46685453/how-to-fill-with-a-different-color-an-area-in-seaborn-distplot/46685832#46685832)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notes at https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

sns.set()

x = np.random.uniform(45,60, 1000)


#With Seaborn
sns.distplot(x)
# fill square defined by x, y0, y1
# need to get pdf and bins generated by sns to do fill between here

## With numpy is easier for me

# density function
y, ybin = np.histogram(x, bins=np.arange(45,61), density=True)

x_points = np.arange(50,56)
x_point_inds = np.arange(5,11)
y0 = np.zeros(6)
y1 = y[x_point_inds]

#With Matplotlib
plt.hist(x,bins=ybin,density=True, zorder=1)
plt.fill_between(x_points, y0, y1, color='g', alpha=0.5, zorder=5)
```